# running selenium test on an headless server with htmlunit

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit

Hi I'm trying to run a simple selenium test on an headless server. I want to use `HtmlUnit` because the server has only `128 mb` of ram so `xvfb+firefox` is unsuitable.

when i run:

`java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite *webdriver http://example.com test.html log.html`

i get this error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: No webdriver session id given`

I guess the problem is I have no `htmlunit` browser installed. Isn't it?

How can I install the htmlunit browser?

Comment: Installation additional packages depends on what operating system and what distribution you are using. Please specify that first.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has some syntax error. I had used selenium server to run a html test suite without webdriver and used the following code:-

java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*browsername" "baseURL" "TestSuite name along with the path" "path and name of report to be generated"

hopefully this will help you..